# How to align an image at left and a heading in centre?

Tags: html, css

I tried using below code but the heading comes in next line.
The code is given below :

```
<div style="display:inline;">
<img src="abc.png" style="margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;width:97px;height:50px;" />
<h5 style="display:inline-block">Hello</h5></div>
```

[image: Incorrect result]
**Expected Output!!**[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your styles like below. Add ***float:left;*** to both ***img and h5 tags*** to get your result.

***UPDATED OUTPUT***

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="display: inline-block;width: 100%;">
    <img src="https://smallbusinesssaturdayuk.com/Images/Small-Business-Saturday-UK-Google-Plus.gif" style="float:left;" />
    <h5 style="text-align:center;">Hello</h5>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I want the image in "left" and the heading in the "center" !

Comment: I'm glad it helped ;)

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
img {
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  width: 97px;
  height: 50px;
  flex: 0 0;
}
h5 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  flex: 1 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.div {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 70px;
}
.img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<h4>Center of text part</h4>
<div>
  <img src="http://beerhold.it/97/50">
  <h5>Hello</h5>
</div>
<hr>
<h4>Center of vieport</h4>
<div class="div">
  <img class="img" src="http://beerhold.it/97/50">
  <h5>Hello</h5>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the image in "left" and the heading in the "center"

Answer (score 1):

Here I used inline styles as you are using that. But always try to avoid inline styles.

```html
<div style="display: inline-block;width: 100%;text-align: center;">
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=12&txt=97%C3%9750&w=97&h=50" alt="img" style="text-align: left;float: left;" />
  <h5 style="margin: 17px 0;">Hello</h5>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its on the same line

```html
<div style="display:inline;background:red; float: left;">
  <img src="http://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/33/33702.png" style="margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;width:97px;height:50px;"><h5 style="display:inline-block; background:blue;color:#fff; vertical-align:top;">Hello</h5></div>
```

Comment: You have changed CSS of OP code. That's why it's working

Comment: So explain what have you changed, instead of stating that *Its on the same line*

Comment: I want the image in "left" and the heading in the "center" !

Answer (score 0):

Use [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) to align elements vertically (does not work for block elements).

```css
div {
  display: inline
}
h5 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
img {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 97px;
  height: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" />
  <h5>Hello</h5>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried to run this in plunker.Still not able to align it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what's your problem. Just try this..

`<div style="display:inline;">
<img src="abc.png" style="float:left; margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;width:97px;height:50px;" />
<h5 style="display:inline-block;">Hello</h5></div>`

Comment: Parent element will be different height if you float image!

Comment: I want the image in "left" and the heading in the "center" !